# How does a Tesla Coil exactly work?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, resonance

How does a [Tesla Coil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil) exactly work? I am currently making a Tesla Coil in school but before I start, I want to know exactly how does a Tesla Coil work? I understand the various electrical components used in it, but what I don't understand is how do those components together work to make something like Tesla Coil.

Comment: There must be a thousand popular science articles on Tesla coils. Go read some and come back to us if you have any questions about specific points.

Comment: I dont understand why there is a spark plug?

Comment: @shauryagupta, spark *gap*.

Comment: http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/10/q-how-does-a-tesla-coil-work-2/ has a description of Tesla Coils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tesla coil is in many ways the same as a transformer and hence if you know the working of one you can understand the working of the other.

Now in common transformers, the coils are couple tightly, so that a large amount of energy transfers from the primary to secondary. This works well at low voltages, but at high voltages the insulating air gap may suffer a dielectric breakdown, thereby becoming the reason for heavy losses. The Tesla coil avoids this and hence can be used at very high voltages.

A Tesla coil consists of two LC oscillators very loosely coupled to each other.  When a charged capacitor is connected to an inductor an electric current will flow from the capacitor through the inductor creating a magnetic field. When the electric field in the capacitor is exhausted the current stops and the magnetic field collapses. As the magnetic field collapses, it induces a current to flow in the inductor in the opposite direction to the original current. This new current charges the capacitor, creating a new electric field, equal but opposite to the original field. As long as the inductor and capacitor are connected the energy in the system will oscillate between the magnetic field and the electric field as the current constantly reverses. The figure below shows a common schematic of the Tesla coil.

[image: Tesla Coil schematic]

When the switch is open, the cap is charged. Now when the switch is closed, the action discussed earlier will cause a magnetic field to be built up in the primary inductor and this in turn will set up a field in the secondary. Since the secondary has a large amount of turns, this will cause an extremely high E field to be built up thereby resulting in large voltages.

The new coils have some additional components, but this is the very basic working of the Tesla coil with minimal components.

Comment: But doesn't a Tesla coil have a spark plug??

Comment: Like I said, this is a simple explanation with the simplest schematic.A spark plug is usually not required (its something totally different), maybe you are confusing it with spark gap. Regardless, this is the explanation as to how the coil actually works. Without telling us what your schematic is, and what parts you are using to build it, you cannot expect us to do more.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-vz82dx6gQ
My schematic is the same as in this video...

Comment: I just saw the video, nowhere is the spark plug mentioned. He says the 'spark gap', which can be thought of as switches working at high voltages used to charge and discharge the caps.

Comment: oops my bad! It is the spark gap I have been talking about!

Comment: Now that you know how the coil works, please accept the answer so that this thread can be marked as an 'answered' thread and be closed.